# How do I remove text after a certain point up to a certain point?

Tags: batch, notepad++, text-editors

I have an XML Database I created for all my ps2 games and the lines for each that that display there title are shown like this `<TITLE>SLUS 999.99.GAMENAME</TITLE>`

What I would like to do is remove the first 12 characters after `<TITLE>` so they read `<TITLE>GAMENAME</TITLE>` I am using Notepad++ don't know if that helps. Is there anyway to do this in bulk or in a batch?

Comment: I think you may be asking too much of Notepad++ here... its advanced text processing features aren't as developed as other tools out there. This is a rather special case too, I don't think many text editors can do things like that.

Answer (score 2):

If everything you want replaced follows that format, a simple regex would do. I'll assume that is the case.

Press `CTRL+H` and on the search mode options, click "Regular Expression".

In the "Find what" section, add this code: `<TITLE>.{12}`. On the "Replace with" section, add the code `<TITLE>`.

More info:

1. [Notepad++ Regular Expressions](https://markantoniou.blogspot.com/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)
2. [Regular Expressions](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=regex+reference&t=brave&ia=cheatsheet)

Comment: Or find `(< TITLE>).{12}`, replace `\1`. Or strictly find `(< TITLE>).{12}(.*< /TITLE>)`, replace `\1\2`.

Comment: look carefully - there is a space after `<` in both opening and closing tags.

Comment: I thought that was a typo but in case it isn't, then you're correct.